# Convert Row Column JSON data

Tags: php, json

I want to create a google chart, but my json URL data like this:

```
{"standings":[{"pos":1,"team":"TEAM A","score":"600","country":"vn"},{"pos":2,"team":"TEAM B","score":"500","country":"us"},{"pos":3,"team":"TEAM C","score":"500","country":"us"},{"pos":4,"team":"TEAM D","score":"200","country":"sg"},{"pos":5,"team":"TEAM E","score":0,"country":"us"}]}
```

I want "score" as row and "Team" as Column. how to make it in PHP ? I have seen this [developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example) but the json data is there row and column, different with my json data.

Comment: Parse the JSON and put it in whatever format you want?

Comment: nothing wrong with your json. Just decode it in whatever  way you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode the existing json string, and loop through it.
Something like this -

```
$json_str = '{"standings":[{"pos":1,"team":"TEAM A","score":"600","country":"vn"},{"pos":2,"team":"TEAM B","score":"500","country":"us"},{"pos":3,"team":"TEAM C","score":"500","country":"us"},{"pos":4,"team":"TEAM D","score":"200","country":"sg"},{"pos":5,"team":"TEAM E","score":0,"country":"us"}]}';
//Decode json
$list = json_decode($json_str,True);
//Loop through existing array and assign to res_list.
$res_list = Array("row" => Array(), "column" => Array());
foreach($list["standings"] as $li_contents){
    $res_list["column"][] = $li_contents["team"];
    $res_list["row"][] = $li_contents["score"];
}
//Encode array back to json.
$json_res = json_encode($res_list);
print_r($json_res);

/*
OUTPUT
{
    "row":["600","500","500","200",0],
    "column":["TEAM A","TEAM B","TEAM C","TEAM D","TEAM E"]
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode()` like this:

```
   <?php $json_data = json_decode($data); ?>
```

Now, you can play with `json_data`